# VBA - Autofilter creates additional condition

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, autofilter

I am having an issue when creating an autofilter on VBA that I cannot resolve looking online.

I am trying to autofilter a table of data based on a condition (> a number). however when I run my code I can see that VBA has added on an additional condition "Begins with (Blanks)" in addition to my desired condition Greater than "x"

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
rng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">" & VolumeMin.Value, _
    Operator:=xlAnd
rng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria2:=">" & MarketCap.Value _
    , Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Can someone point out what is causing VBA to create this additional unwanted condition? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Criteria2:=` on `Field:=3` without specifying a `Criteria1:=`.  Excel is therefore using a "default" `Criteria1:=` of "Begins with".

Try the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
rng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">" & VolumeMin.Value, _
    Operator:=xlAnd
rng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">" & MarketCap.Value, _
    Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue